# Creating a dictionary from another two in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries:

```
movies = {"Fences": "Viola Davis", "Hick": "Blake Lively",
           "The Hunger Games": "Jennifer Lawrence"}
```

and

```
tvshows = {"How to Get Away with Murder": "Viola Davis",
            "Gossip Girl": "Blake Lively",
            "The Office": "Steve Carrell"}
```

and I want as a result of these two the next dictionary where if a value is repeated in movies and tvshows must appear as follows :

```
{"Viola Davis": ["Fences", "How to Get Away with Murder"],
   "Steve Carrell": ["The Office"], "Jennifer Lawrence":
   ["The Hunger Games"], "Blake Lively": ["Hick",
   "Gossip Girl"]}
```

My code until now is:

```
tv_movies = { actor : [ program for program, actor in tvshows.items() if actor == actor  ] for movie, actor in movies.items()  }
```

but I get the following output:

```
print(tv_movies)
```

**{'Viola Davis': ['The Office', 'How to Get Away with Murder', 'Gossip Girl'], 'Jennifer Lawrence': ['The Office', 'How to Get Away with Murder', 'Gossip Girl'], 'Blake Lively': ['The Office', 'How to Get Away with Murder', 'Gossip Girl']}**

I´m stuck here, can you help me please?. Thank you very much

Comment: That's a really bad setup. But just create a 2d-array / matrix / sparse-matrix of movie/actor connections and iterate both dicts. When there is an entry, mark true. If it's true, it stays true. (Especially in the dense-case this needs you to map movies to some (0, N) id-range and the same for actors).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
from collections import ChainMap, defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for title, actor in ChainMap(movies, tvshows).items():
    d[actor].append(title)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but when I run the code at the begining of the dictionary appears a **defaultdict(<class 'list'>,** how can I get rid of it in front of the dictionary?

Comment: You can run `del d.[defaultdict]`

Comment: @myString It shows this thing because it is not a standard dictionary, but an instance of `defaultdict` class with `list` as default factory. You can do `dict(d)` to convert it back.

Answer (score 0):

ChainMap is supported from V3.3, so here is code that is compatible with python V2.x and 3.x

```
lis = [movies, tvshows] #make a list of dictionaries - movies, tvshows, etc..
d = {}
for element in lis:
    for key, value in element.items():
        if value not in d.keys():
            d[value] = [key]
        else:
            d[value].append(key)
```